# Where's the 'similar layers' functions in Photoshop CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, creative-cloud

In previous versions it used to be under `Select > Similar layers` but I can't find it anymore.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why `Select similar layers` was removed is because CC incorporates a way of ***filtering*** layers in the layer menu:

[image]